# What does the # and ## means in C preprocessor macro of c++

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

I read the following code:

```
#define MACRO(abc, def) {#def ## #abc}

char result[10] = MARCO(abc, def);
```

I know the `##` operator is used to merge the two string to one, but what about the `#` in front of `def` and `abc`?

Comment: This is documented in the manual of the preprocessor. Look it up.

Comment: Presumably "MARCO" will give a compiler error.

Comment: And concatenating two string literals into a single token will also give an error.

Comment: I disagree with the above - finding the answer on Stack Overflow is a lot easier than finding and digging through the documentation.  I can never remember which is which, which is what Google is for - and a quick Google search drops me right into this Stack Overflow entry and answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

From the standard (emphasis mine):

> **16.3.2 The # operator [cpp.stringize]**
>
> 2/ A character string literal is a string-literal with no prefix. **If, in the replacement list, a parameter is immediately preceded by a # preprocessing token, both are replaced by a single character string literal** preprocessing token that contains the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding argument. **[...]**

It "stringifies" the token following the `#`.

Example:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x

STRINGIFY(foo)  // will be replaced by "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Stringizing Operator (#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx)**

> The number-sign or "stringizing" operator (#) converts macro parameters to string literals without expanding the parameter definition. It is used only with macros that take arguments. If it precedes a formal parameter in the macro definition, the actual argument passed by the macro invocation is enclosed in quotation marks and treated as a string literal.

So,

```
char result[10] = MACRO(abc, def);
```

will expand to:

```
char result[10] = "def" ## "abc";
```

Which will expand to:

```
char result[10] = "defabc";
```

*For those who say it won't work / won't compile: I tested and ran this in MS VS2010*

Comment: It won't compile on any standard-conforming compiler: http://ideone.com/noE2cd. `"def""abc"` is not a valid token, even if your compiler happens to interpret it as intended.

Comment: @MikeSeymour interestingly ideone doesn't mind the following: printf("hello""world"); is that conforming code? I'm curious as I sometimes do this to split strings into multiple lines.